# What are the Steps needed to use NUnit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing

I Developed a small Application in C#. I want to test my application with NUnit.I am a new to NUnit.I Installed NUnit but don't Know How to use it what are the basic steps needed for it or please provide me a good reference link about using NUnit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [References/guides for nunit unit testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139999/references-guides-for-nunit-unit-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to have an own project for your tests (like `Project.Tests`).

Place the following basic files somewhere in folder of your project structure (e.g. `lib\nunit\nunit`):

- `nunit.core.dll`
- `nunit.core.interfaces.dll`
- `nunit.framework.dll`
- `nunit.util.dll`
- `nunit-console.exe`
- `nunit-console.exe.config`
- `nunit-console-runner.dll`
- `nunit-console-x86.exe`
- `nunit-console-x86.exe.config`

Then you need to reference the `NUnit.Framework` assembly in your `Project.Tests` project.

For example, a simple test would look like this:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Project.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void MyTestMethod()
        {
            var a = "a";
            var b = "a";
            Assert.AreEqual(a, b);
        }
    }
}
```

You can run this test then for example with the [NUnit-console](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-console&r=2.2) or directly in VisualStudio (e.g. with the help of [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html)) or through a MSBuild task with the help of [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Check out [the NUnit quick start](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.4):

> Let’s start with a simple example.
>   Suppose we are writing a bank
>   application and we have a basic domain
>   class – Account. Account supports
>   operations to deposit, withdraw, and
>   transfer funds.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use resharper I recommend you to use this plugin - http://www.testdriven.net/ .